# How to add to the result of a template call in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Suppose the following template call generates and outputs a result of $20,000 and given that I have another element called sCost which occurs only once and has a value of 385, how could I add to the result of the template call?

```
<xsl:call-template name="totalCost">
   <xsl:with-param name="list" select="/delivery/manifest/item" /> 
</xsl:call-template>
```

When I try to do the following I get NaN...

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar">
    <xsl:call-template name="totalCost">
        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="/delivery/manifest/item" /> 
    </xsl:call-template>    
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$myVar + ../sCost" />
```

Comment: Please post enough code (XML + XSLT) to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the result contains the ‘$‘ character, then it is not considered to be a number. Perform the currency formatting only as the last step in the process.

Comment: Thank you so much, these are things I would have never even thought of!